# Split file into separate files based on content of column + add header & record totals for each new file

Tags: text-processing

- Header starts with H
- Trailer starts with T
- Record starts with R
- Delimited by '|'

input file sample

- Trailer record 3rd column has count of the records and 4th column is the sum of the amount column
- After splitting, trailer should be added in the new file with the below format having  count and sum columns
- INPUT records will not follow the date order sequence. ex: 1st rec has 2019-03-05 rec and also the last record is also the same date.

Input file:

```
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-05|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|20.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
T|20200425|8|225.00
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

File 1: should be saved as `20190305.txt`

```
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-05|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|20.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
T|20200425|4|90.00
```

File 2: should be saved as `20190306.txt`

```
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
T|20200425|4|135.00
```

Comment: Hi there! We will be glad to give you a help if you show your own efforts toward a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution

```
awk -F'[|]' '
     $1=="H"{h=$0"sum"; next}
     $1=="R"{o=$3".txt";gsub("-","",o);
           if (! sum[o]) print h > o; 
           printf ("%s|%s|%s|%.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4) > o; sum[o]+=$4; c[o]++}
     $1=="T"{for (o in sum) printf ("%s|%s|%d|%.2f\n", $1, $2, c[o], sum[o]) > o}' file;
tail -n +1 2019*.txt
```

**Output**

```
==> 20190305.txt <==
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-05|10.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|20.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
T|20200425|3|60.00

==> 20190306.txt <==
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
T|20200425|3|125.00
```

**Walkthrough**

Set the `FS` to `|`

```
awk -F'[|]' '
```

If its a header line, catch it, add the missing text and jump to the next line

```
     $1=="H"{h=$0"sum"; next}
```

If it's a record then grab `$3".txt"` and strip the `-` to get the output file name

```
     $1=="R"{o=$3".txt";gsub("-","",o);
```

If the sum array for this output file has not yet been initialised then `print` the header to file

```
           if (! sum[o]) print h > o;
```

Format the output, correcting the last field and `printf` to the relevant file

```
           printf ("%s|%s|%s|%.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4) > o;
```

Update your `sum` and record `c`ount for this output file using the filename as the index

```
           sum[o]+=$4; c[o]++}
```

If it's a tailender iterate over the sum array to recover the filenames, compose and `printf` the summary line relevant to each `o`utput file

```
     $1=="T"{for (o in sum) printf ("%s|%s|%d|%.2f\n", $1, $2, c[o], sum[o]) > o}' file;
```

Show the output

```
tail -n +1 2019*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in `awk`:

`if($0 ~ /^$/){next};` → ignore if its empty line

`if(NR==1){hd=$0;h=1;next}` → Store the header in *'hd'* variable and go to next line to parse.

`f=$3$4$5` → Store the filename in *'f'* variable ( since '-' is also a delimiter its value separated and available i*n ${3,4,5}* respectively.Finally during printing we append ".txt"

```
awk -F'[|-]' '{
    if($0 ~ /^$/){next};
    if(NR==1){hd=$0;h=1;dt=$2;next}
    f=$3$4$5;sum+=$6;c++;
    if ( dval != f ) { h=1;printf "%s|%s|%s|%.2f\n","T",dt,c,v6 >> dval".txt";temp=$6;sum=0;c=0};
    if ($0 ~ /^T/ ) { next; }
    if ($0 ~ /^R/ ){v6=sum+temp;}
    if(h){print hd"\n\n"$0"\n" > f".txt"; h=0;}else{ print $0"\n" >> f".txt";}dval=f;
    }' inputFile
```

Output :

```
$ cat 20190305.txt 
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-05|10.00    
R|abc|2019-03-05|20.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
T|20200425|3|60.00

$ cat 20190306.txt 
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
T|20200425|3|125.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above solution. I'm trying from my end in a different way but got stuck in adding the amount value I double. I could see in your output, sum value in Trailer is an integer not double. Is there any way to handle the double value?

Comment: @hunter : Updated the answer with for floating point requirement.

Comment: @bu5hman : the edited question doesn't have actual input what OP provided ...it has empty lines with it and he wanted the output like the same ( with new empty lines ) . so i used it...

Comment: Fair enough old chap, better change mine to `=="R"` from `!="T"` then just in case OP changes back!!!

Comment: Okay sure old chap ... yea may be...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```c
awk -F'|' '
  # get the 2nd field of the header
  NR == 1 { 
    a = $2 
    h = $0
    next
  } 
  # get the date formatted
  NR == 2 { 
    d = $3; gsub(/-/,"",d) 
    print h > d
  } 
  # if the line starts with 'R', sum the column and get the count of them
  $1 == "R" { 
    sum += $4
    ++c 
  } 
  {
    print > d
  }
  # print the final line with variables acquired
  END { 
    OFS = "|"; print "T",a,c,sum".00" > d
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
$ cat 20190305.txt 
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-05|10.00    
R|abc|2019-03-05|20.00
R|abc|2019-03-05|30.00
T|20200425|3|60.00

$ cat 20190306.txt 
H|20200425|abcd|sum
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
T|20200425|3|125.00
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the above problem other than AWK? I have updated the Input/output in the problem. In the source file, I may get different dates in different rows no sequence is guaranteed. I have developed a code using for loop based on the date column to split into new files. But I got stuck when the dates are not sequential. Can anyone help with the solution in other than awk as I'm worried if some IO issue occurs it is hard to track down when we use AWK.